# Intercommunity Reputation Leagues

Tags: feature-request, network-profile, reputation-leagues

SE has [Reputation Leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues) for different communities, which are fun and enhance competition (willingness to participate) among users. Can we have a Stack Exchange Network reputation league, where users will be ranked as per the total reputation they have across all the SE networks.

Comment: @ShadowWizard this is a feature request, and that question asks if this is possible.

Comment: Because it's not possible, and that question has [feature-request] tag, it *is* a feature request.

Comment: Your question "*Can we have a Stack Exchange Network reputation league*" the other question "*Can we see which people have the most network-wide reputation*" = dupe :) Just add a bounty on the other question, or an answer if you have more arguments or ideas to add :)